# Integrating google login to static html

Tags: google-signin

I'm trying to integrate google login page to static html page. All I have to do is, when user clicks on google login button, he gets google credentials page and upon successful authentication I wanted to display basic info values in html page. Here's the code I have. I'm successfully able to login but after that I'm not able to see values getting printed. Any help?

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<ClientID>">
    <title>My Web app</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="profileinfo"></div>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        alert("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        alert('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
    }
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont have error handling also, which is hard to debug.

another way is to do like this:

```
function onSignIn () {

  var instance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

        instance.signIn().then((response) => {

                var user = response.getBasicProfile();

                var data = {
                 id: user.getId(),
                 email: user.getEmail(),
                 name: user.getName(),
                 // etc
                }

                console.log(data);

              },
              err => {
              // error handling 
              console.log(error);
              });

     }
```